# If $H$ is a hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$ Then $\Lambda:H \to H$ positive definite implies $\Lambda^{-1}$ exists and is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

In my textbook there is a result that says:

If $H$ is a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\Lambda:H \to H$ is a bounded linear operator which satisfies $$(\Lambda x,x)\geq \beta\|x\|$$ for some $\beta>0$ and all $x \in H$ then $\Lambda^{-1}$ exists and satisfies $$\|\Lambda^{-1}\|\leq \frac{1}{\beta}.$$

Does an analagous result hold if $H$ is taken to be over $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Lambda$ is injective: $\Lambda(x)=0$ implies that $(\Lambda(x),x)=0\geq\beta\|x\|$. This implies that $x=0$.

$\Lambda$ is surjective. Consider $L=\overline{(\Lambda(H)}$ the adherence of the image of $H$. If $L\neq H$, consider $x$ in the orthogonal of $L$, $x\neq 0$, $(\Lambda(x),x)=0\geq \beta\|x\|$ implies that $x=0$. Contradiction.

Let $x\in H$, $x=lim_n\Lambda(x_n)$. For every $c>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n,m>N$ implies that $\|\Lambda(x_n)-\Lambda(x_m)\|\leq c$. This implies that ${1\over \beta}\|x_n-x_m\|\leq \|\Lambda(x_n-x_m)\|\leq c$. We deduce that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and converges towards $y$ since $H$ is complete. We have $\Lambda(y)=lim_n\Lambda(x_n)=x$. We deduce that $\Lambda(H)=H$.

$\Lambda$ is bijective and continue, the open map theorem implies that its inverse is bounded. I have not used any property of $\mathbb{R}$ in the proof so the result is true for $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

yes, if $(\Lambda x,x)$ is real for every $x\in H$ (complex Hilbert space) then $\Lambda$ is self-adjoint [see e.g. Rudin, Functional analysis, 12.32].
If it verifies the lower bound $(\Lambda x,x) \geq \beta (x,x)$ then it is invertible with the bound you state for the inverse. This is because 
$\beta \|x\| \; \|x\| \leq \|x\| \; \|Tx\|$ implies that $T$ is injective, whence has closed image and the lower bound also implies that is has a trivial orthogonal complement.